# Android read calendar events

Tags: android, calendar, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to create a interface to choose calenar events but I have run into some issues. On my devices I get the correct events but many of my users have reported the functionality isn't working and some shows events that aren't even in the calendar. On a 4.1 Samsung device I tested on the app crashed so what I'm wondering is; what is the correct way to display a list of all calendar events? Here's the  code I'm using right now:

```
 Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse
("content://com.android.calendar/events"),
 new String[]{"calendar_id", "title", "description",
"dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation"}, "calendar_id=1", null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int length = cursor.getCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                CalendarEvent ce = new CalendarEvent();

                ce.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                ce.setNote(cursor.getString(2));
                ce.setDate(cursor.getLong(3));

                if (cursor.getString(1).length() > 0) {
                    mItems.add(ce);
                }

                cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suspect that the culprit is this condition: `"calendar_id=1"`.

A device can have multiple calendars. It's not guaranteed that the one with id=1 is the primary one (and even if you used the primary one, the user may have events in multiple different calendars -- e.g. personal and work).

So, it depends on what you want to do exactly. You should either:

- use the primary calendar (the one with [`IS_PRIMARY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.CalendarColumns.html#IS_PRIMARY), but see caveat above), or
- have the user select a single calendar for using your app (querying the [Calendars table](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Calendars.html)) and then using that `calendar_id` from then on, or
- if you want events from *all* calendars, remove the `calendar_id` filter.